# Can Mike McCauley bcm2835 C library access all 26/28 GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi 2 Mod B?

Tags: gpio

Can Mike McCauley bcm2835 C library access all 26/28 GPIO pins on Raspberry Pi 2 Mod B?

Comment: oops - your right, should be 26.

Comment: I couldn't see any constants for the Pi2.  The pin out is the same for the A+/B+/Pi2 so you could use the BPLUS defines.

Answer (score 1):

There are [constants defined](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__constants.html#ga63c029bd6500167152db4e57736d0939) for all the pins, so the answer is yes.